# Java Html form processing not returning entered data string

Tags: java

Trying to automate this html form filling and get return the data on the next page.The data passed  is not returning the way to match what is in the site.
This is the code:

```
parseSite() throws Exception
{
     Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
  data.put("txtEntryReg1", "35806573CB");
    data.put("txtEntryReg2", "35806573CB");
   data.put("t3", "8/30/2013 2:37:30 AM*");
   data.put("t3", "4:3844: 1NB/9143/21 *");

 data.put("btnSubmit2","+Print+Your+Payment+Invoice");
  //data.putAll("txtEntryReg1=35278160IG&txtEntryReg2=35278160IG&t3=4%3A3623%3A+5NB%2F9143%2F21+*&t3=8%2F30%2F2013+2%3A15%3A24+AM*&btnSubmit2=+Print+Your+Payment+Invoice");
     //data.putAll(data);

     //key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3

        doSubmit("http://poters.com.ng/mo/std/acp_slp/1/default.aszp", data);

}

    public void doSubmit(String url, Map<String, String> data) throws Exception {
    URL siteUrl = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) siteUrl.openConnection();
           // conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "__utma=244564033.513877751.1371763186.1376824439.1376824439.39; __utmc=244564033; __utmz=244564033.1373732391.30.3.utmcsr=login.lionet50.net|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/login");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    Set keys = data.keySet();
    Iterator keyIter = keys.iterator();
    String content = "";

            for(int i=0; keyIter.hasNext(); i++) {
        Object key = keyIter.next();
        if(i!=0) {
            content += "&";
        }
        content += key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(data.get(key), "UTF-8");
    }


    System.out.println(content);
    out.writeBytes(content);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
}`
```

The data when printed i.e System.out.println(content). returns

`&t3=4%3A3844%3A+1NB%2F9143%2F21+*&txtEntryReg2=35806573CB&btnSubmit2=%2BPrint%2BYour%2BPayment%2BInvoice`

but i want it to print
 `txtEntryReg1=35278160IG&txtEntryReg2=35278160IG&t3=+%3A3112%3A+8NB%2F0%2F213422*&t3=9%2F1%2F2013+12%3A00%3A17+AM*&btnSubmit=+Create+Payment+Invoice`

Have tried changing the data.put(...,...) order but nothing still working.
Somebody pls help

Answer (score 1):

That's because a `HashMap` does not preserve the order in which the records are inserted. You can use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

But, why does the order matter?

Comment: The order matters because the site i am testing returns the parsed in records in this order "txtEntryReg1=35278160IG&txtEntryReg2=35278160IG&t3=+%3A3112%3A+8NB%2F0%2F213422*&t3=9%2F1%2F2013+12%3A00%3A17+AM*&btnSubmit=+Create+Payment+Invoice"     But the one mine is returning in this order "&t3=4%3A3844%3A+1NB%2F9143%2F21+*&txtEntryReg2=35806573CB&btnSubmit2=%2BPrint%2BYour%2BPayment%2BInvoice"

Answer (score 0):

There is no such problem in your code except for the following:

You are putting the value for `t3` twice, so the map will override it and you will get only one value. Also, `LinkedHashMap` will help in getting the order maintained. I am not sure if that is the priority.

And if you are worried about the encoded URL, please use URL decoding to get what you can read. This can be used like below:

```
    URLDecoder.decode(encodedURL)
```

Comment: Wow!!! Thanks Henry and dharam. Its working well now... The problem is just the ordering which I changed to LinkedHashMap. Thanks again